# warning: object backing the pointer will be destroyed at the end of the full-expression for std::pair

Tags: c++, c++17, stdstring, temporary, string-view

Following code gives the dangling pointer error.

```
    std::vector<std::pair<std::string, int>> c;
    for (auto& b : c) {
        const auto& [s, i] = b;
        std::string_view v = s.substr(i);
        std::cout << v;
    }
```

I think that `b` holds the reference to the `std::pair<std::string, int>`, so `s` should be the reference to the string in pair object. Why does this creates the dangling pointer error? What am I missing here? godbolt link: https://godbolt.org/z/4zMvbr

Comment: It'd be helpful if you mention which line that error happens

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In `std::string_view v = s.substr(i);`, [`std::string::substr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) returns `std::string` by value, i.e. it returns a temporary `std::string`. `std::string` could be [converted](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_basic_string_view) to `std::string_view` implicitly, which is constructed from `std::string::data()`, i.e. the pointer to the underlying array of the temporary `std::string`. After the full expression, the temporary `std::string` is destroyed and the pointer held by `std::string_view` becomes dangling pointer.

> It is the programmer's responsibility to ensure that the resulting
> string view does not outlive the string.
>
> ```
> std::string get_string();
> int f(std::string_view sv);
>  
> int x = f(get_string()); // OK
> std::string_view sv = get_string(); // Bad: holds a dangling pointer
> ```

Comment: I see. So should I do something like string_view v(s.c_str() + i); ?

Comment: @Jaebum Yes, it should be fine.